# AVFoundation Photo output brighter than preview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, swift4

I have a custom camera using AVFoundation. I have now noticed a problem where the previewLayer is darker than the photo that is captured and outputted. In other words, the final photo is brighter than what was previewed on the previewLayer. I have researched this issue and read other stack overflow questions, but no one has had this problem.

Here is a video showing the problem: [Final Photo brighter than previewLayer](https://youtu.be/yuf_7YGfDQY)

What could be the problem? Has anyone had this problem, if so how did they fix it?

Comment: through my testing with multiple phones, this problem may be associated with an internal camera problem (hardware) on my iPhone 6S...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, I have determined that the issue was, in fact, a hardware issue related to my iPhone 6S, not an error with my camera code. A component of my phone's camera was damaged.